# Adding customizer styles with wp_add_inline_style

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer, wp-enqueue-style

As I [told in an earlier question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/226855/is-the-theme-customizer-slowing-down-my-site) is have a theme with hundreds of mods, which I gather in one mod so I don't have to loop through all mods at every pageload.

Now, the [codex has you dump customizer styles](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API#Part_2:_Generating_Live_CSS) directly in the head, which isn't very elegant. There is [`wp_add_inline_style`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style) to add css in an orderly way to an existing style sheet. This looks like this and it works fine:

```
$style = get_theme_mod ('all-mods');
wp_add_inline_style ('my-main-style',$style);
```

There's one problem, however. If I build a child theme, the inline styles are still added directly after the parent styles. This causes them to be overruled by the child theme css, which is loaded after the parent's to make sure it overrides those styles. This is not what the user expects.

The customizer styles should have the highest priority, so in some way I must make sure they are the last ones to be loaded in the head. I can detect if there's a [child theme active](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_child_theme), but cannot know the handle of the child style to add the inline styles to it.

At this moment I have simply defined an empty css file, which I enqueue right at the end of the head, and then add the inline styles. But this is far from elegant, which is why I took this path in the first place. Does anybody know of a smarter approach?

Comment: Personally I don't see the problem with the codex's suggestion - just use a very late hook on `wp_head` and output a `<style>` tag. Ultimately, this is what you want - to ensure the customizer styles take priority over everything else.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to detect if the current used theme is a child and if so pointing the inline CSS to the right style. I didn't tested this solution but could be a good starting point.

```
function mytheme_enqueue_style()
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-theme-style',get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', false );

    if(is_child_theme())
    {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'child-theme-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('parent-theme-style')  );
    }

    $style = get_theme_mod ('all-mods');
    $where = is_child_theme() ? 'child-theme-style' : 'parent-theme-style';
    wp_add_inline_style( $where, $style );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enqueue_style' );
```

### NOTE

There is a difference between `get_template_directory_uri()` and `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` in fact [on codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) we have

> In the event a child theme is being used, this function will return
>   the child's theme directory URI. Use `get_template_directory_uri()` to
>   avoid being overridden by a child theme.